# Binding a tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make my own tkinter widgets which allow for more customization and are more aesthetically pleasing. A key concept that I will be utilizing is the `bind()` method, which I will most notably use to make buttons out of labels bound to the `<Button-1>` event (in order to get ride of the irremovable border of the preinstalled tkinter buttons and add some cool effects).

The general code so far looks like this...

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def something(event):
    print(event.widget)

def Custom_Button(master, text):
    return(Label(master, text = text))

mywidget = Custom_Button(root, text = 'goodbye')
mywidget.bind('<Button-1>', something)
mywidget.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The issue that I have with this setup is the separate line needed to bind the `<Button-1>` to my custom widget. I am wondering if there is a way to specify within the `CustomButton()` function that `mywidget` should be bound to `<Button-1>`. The problem is that `mywidget` is assigned to the value returned by the function `CustomButton()`.

Essentially I wondering how I can change the code to make something like this that actually work?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def something(event):
    print(event.widget)

def Custom_Button(master, text):
    return(Label(master, text = text))
    #this
    mywidget.bind('<Button-1>', something)
    #or this
    bind('<Button-1>', something)

mywidget = Custom_Button(root, text = 'goodbye')
mywidget.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you think there's an "irremovable border"? Except on OSX you can set the `borderwidth` to zero which removes the border, and you can set `highlightthickness` to zero to remove the highlight ring.

Comment: Because I am on OSX and I like my widgets to look pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways. The first is just like you're doing, except that you need to move the `return` function to the last line of the function:

```
def Custom_Button(master, text):
    label = Label(master, text=text)
    label.bind(...)
    ...
    return label
```

The second is to use an object-oriented approach where you create a custom class. Since you are only creating a single label, you can inherit from `Label`:

```
class Custom_Cutton(Label):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Label.__init__(self, *args)
        self.bind(...)
        ...
```

Note: there's nothing unique about doing this for tkinter. This is the same for any python function or object.

Comment: Yeah I realized the second I posted that classes would be a better idea, but I have not completely wrapped my mind around the concept of them. I can't believe I didn't think of your first solution because it is pretty straightforward, and thanks for explaining how to do it with classes!!